# reading space with writeUTF() using RandomAccessFile

Tags: java

what i wanna try to do is reading a space from the input and write in into my textfile using RandomAccessFile (the reason of using randomaccessfile is i want to modify and delete my rows or objects without creating or rewriting the whole text file again).
but unfortunately, when i enter space for one of these variables, i can't write space into the text file and it just skip the next input. do you have any idea how to solve this issue and write the space with other characters using file.writeUTF(name) ?

code:
http://pastebin.com/3GgQsgNF

Comment: Use `nextLine()` instead of `next()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't write space into the text file and it just skip the next
>   input.

Use `nextLine()` instead of `next()`.

`next()` will only return what comes before a space.

`nextLine()` automatically moves the scanner down after returning the current line.

```
name = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();
```

[Scanner doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `scanner.nextLine()` instead of `scanner.next()`.

For example :

```
System.out.println("name: ");
name = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();
```